# Close the Solution Explorer window

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut to close the Solution Explorer window? I know how to open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. How do we close it?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> is what I needed.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to bring the Solution Explorer into focus.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it.

Close Tool Window: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: You can also close it (using English menus) with Alt-W(indow)-H(ide), once it has the focus, for which I use Alt-V(iew)-(Solution ex)p(lorer).